# Callstack for std::bad_function_call

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I have a linux program which terminates with:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'`

In the call stack I sadly don't see from where the bad function is called.
Also it does very much iterations before generating this error, so I cannot really debug it by hand.

Is there a way to get to the problematic piece of code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can you set a [catchpoint](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html) from gdb? You'll want to execute

```
catch throw
```

from gdb command line before running the program, and then a breakpoint will be hit when an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly, what I was searching for.

Answer (score 4):

You can use gdb to see where the exception is being thrown:

```
(gdb) catch throw
```

That will stop whenever a new exception is thrown in your program, and you will see where it happened.

Answer (score 2):

please reference to this website. In my case, this problem was caused by using null function pointer.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bad_function_call/